# Are these two graphs (trees) isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image: graph 1]

[image: graph 2]

I would say they are not isomorphic since the node with degree 4 is in two different positions, any suggestion?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Consider the vertex of valency $4$ ... What are the valencies of the $4$ verticies it is adjacent to ? ... these differ in each case.

Comment: You could talk about how a trail of length 3 does not exist between two nodes of degree 1 in the second graph, but does in the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Théophile and Bram28 say, you are indeed correct, but you do need to explain this in a more technical way.

I find that the other two answers are a bit *too* complicated though...  more so than they need be. To show that they are non-isomorphic, all that you need to do is say that in the second graph, the degree-$4$ vertex is adjacent to three leaves (degree-$1$ vertex) and in the first, it is adjacent to only two leaves.

Comment: Not sure I follow

Comment: @Shuri2060 Two graphs are *isomorphic* if there exists a *one-to-one* mapping between their vertices. However, the mapping cannot happen with these two graphs. Here's why: each graph has exactly one vertex of degree $4$, so those vertices would have to correspond. But in one graph, the degree $4$ vertex is adjacent only to $2$ leaves, whereas in the other, it is adjacent to $3$. Thus there can be no correspondence between the leaves.

Comment: I follow after the edit :p

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. To make this a bit more 'mathematically acceptable': By definition of graph isomorphism, for them to be isomorph, there needs to be a bijection $f$ between the nodes of the two graphs such that nodes $i$ and $j$ in Graph 1 are connected if and only if $f(i)$ and $f(j)$ in Graph 2 are connected.

So, to possibly get such a mapping, you clearly have to map node 4 of Graph 1 to node 1 of Graph 2, but now you have exactly 2 nodes in Graph 1 that are adjacent to node 4 in graph 1, so you also need exactly 2 nodes in Graph 2 that are adjacent to node 1 in Graph 2, but in fact you have 3 nodes like that, so no isomorphism is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give examples of proofs that these two tree are not isomorphic. Let me say something more general about proving that two graphs are not isomorphic.

In general, a good way to show that two graphs are not isomorphic is to find some *structural property* that one graph has but the other doesn't. A structural property is technically a property of a graph that is preserved under isomorphism, but the term can be thought of as any property that doesn't depend on how you draw the graph. In this case, "vertices 2 and 6 are five centimeters away from each other" is not a structural property, but "the vertex of degree four has three adjacent leafs" is a structural property. The best proofs of nonisomorphism find the clearest structural properties.